# how to store input text box value into php variable without form submit,without js,without jquery and without ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a text box and a button. When I click the button, a function should be called in which I can store the text box value into a variable. 
But no javascript, Ajax, jquery, form submit should be used

Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into? Yes, what you ask is possible.

Comment: No this isn't possible. The fact that you use the term "function" should tell you this isn't possible without js.

Comment: You don't want to use any client side framework then where you want to create a function and store its value, in mind or in cloud ? :)

Comment: "Calling a function without any language" is a nonsense. A function is necessarily part of a language.

Comment: You should use a server side language, such as PHP.
have a look on it: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the action attribute inside the form tag to refer to a PHP script that receives the value and saves it onto a variable.

Example:

HTML Form

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="variable" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

PHP File

```
<?php
$variable = $_POST['variable'];
// do whatever with $variable
?>
```

This is a simple code to explain how you can do what you're asking, without JS, Jquery or Ajax, and using the form submit.

Comment: it is mentioned in the question that **but no java script, Ajax, j query , form submit should be used**, still you are giving example using form submit..

Comment: This is not what the OP asked. It is my opinion this question should just be closed.

Comment: That's exactly what OP asked for.No javascript no php no form submits

Comment: @cssGEEK there is a form submit... So its not what OP asked

Comment: @DarkBee i am not sure If OP knows what he is asking for

Comment: @cssGEEK that is entirely true :)

Comment: In my opinion, the OP didn't know what he wanted, so I gave the simplest possible answer. If I take the OP's question literally, then no, it isn't possible. I just prefer to give a possible solution around the problem, than a simple "no".